# Returning only a single value after an iteration

Tags: java, loops, methods, multidimensional-array

I have to make a method that takes a price(a value) located on a multi dimensional array and it needs to return only one set of coordinates. The issues is other positions have the same value so it returns all coordinates at the position, not just the first one.

```
 public static int availSeats(int a[][], int seatPrice){
    int seats=seatPrice;
    for(int row=0;row<rows;row++){
        for(int col=0;col<cols;col++){

            if(seats==a[row][col]){
                int priceRow=row;
                int priceCol=col;
            System.out.println("Seat: "+priceRow+","+priceCol);

            }
        }}

    return seats;
}
```

Comment: No. What the method returns (`seats`) is the `seatPrice` it takes as argument. You're confusing *printing to the console* and *returning a value*. You can't return coordinates (two values) from a method returning a single int.

Comment: Also, if you want to stop the execution at the first seatprice you find, include a "break" statement after the System.out.println call.

Comment: he could return an array

Comment: ... and the return type `int` is not particularly suitable for representation of *coordinates*.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be returning only one value however it is printing all. I am assuming the return value is correct and is what you are actually expecting. So avoid the confusion, add label on your outer loop and break it when you encounter first satisfying coordinates . for example, change your code as below :

```
        int seats=seatPrice;
        outerloop:
        for(int row=0;row<rows;row++){
            for(int col=0;col<cols;col++){

                if(seats==a[row][col]){
                    int priceRow=row;
                    int priceCol=col;
                System.out.println("Seat: "+priceRow+","+priceCol);
                break outerloop;
                }
            }}

        return seats;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about goal, but I guess a List could help:

```
public static List<Coordinate> availSeats(int a[][], int seatPrice){
    List<Coordinate> coords= new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
    int seats=seatPrice;
    for(int row=0;row<rows;row++){
        for(int col=0;col<cols;col++){

            if(seats==a[row][col]){
                int priceRow=row;
                int priceCol=col;
                coords.add(new Coordinate(row, col));
                System.out.println("Seat: "+priceRow+","+priceCol);
        }
    }}

return coords;
```

}

where *Coordinate* is a simple class containing two int fields: row and col.